# Ajax partial view not updating parent div

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a problem with using an ajax button in a partial view to update a div in the parent page. If I put the same button into the parent page it works fine. Is this not possible or am I missing something? cheers for the help

Parent View:

```
<div id="topiclist">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("DetailLoader", this.Model);}
</div>
```

Partial View

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("LatestTopics", "Forums", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId =     "topiclist" }))
{ 

<input type="hidden" name="page" value="@ViewBag.page" />
 <input type="submit" id="refresh" class="latestbuttons" value="@(ViewBag.NewTopics) New Topics" />
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Include this line in your views, I had the same issue and it worked for me !

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```